# Nginx Too many open files although not close to limit

Tags: nginx

The error log is filled w/ `Too many open files`.
I increased the ulimit and fs.file-max to very high numbers (and validated the change via `sysctl -a | grep fs.file-max` and `ulimit -n` on the nginx's user).

`lsof | wc -l` indicate that very few file-descriptors are open and are no where near the limits.

more info:
nginx version: 1.15.7
linux version: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1072-aws x86_64)

what else could cause this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you set "worker_rlimit_nofile" in nginx.conf ?

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://serverfault.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: no I did not. I was unaware such config. was required in addition to the OS one. Thank you very much!